# Why casting short* to int* shows incorrect value

Tags: c, pointers

To better learn how `malloc` and pointers work internally, I created an array of `short`. On my system, `int` is double the size of `short`, so I created another pointer `q` of type `int*` and set its address to the casted value of `p`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    short* p = (short*) malloc(2 * sizeof(short));
    int* q = (int*) p;
    
    assert(sizeof *q == 2 * sizeof *p);
    
    p[0] = 0;
    p[1] = 1;
    
    printf("%u\n", *q);
}
```

When I print `*q` it shows the number `65536` instead of `1` and I can't figure out why. If I understand correctly, `p` should be represented as the following (assuming short is 2 bytes and int is 4 bytes):

```
        p[0]                  p[1]
0000 0000 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

So `*q` should read 4 bytes hence reading the value `1`. Instead it shows `65536` which is represented as:

```
0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: You might do a bit research on "endianess". You have wrong expectations how the bytes of an `int` are located in memory.

Comment: Check the binary representation of 65536 and compare it to the one you expect. What do you notice? You can also try with other numbers, instead of 0 and 1, to better see the pattern.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica it's 2^16 But I'm expecting 1 not 65536

Comment: You should repeat your tests with a better bit pattern. Try `p[0]=0x0102; p[1]=0x0304;` and see what is printed. For this you should better use `%x` for printing in hex format.

Comment: Try with p[0] = 65280 (which is 1111 1111 0000 0000) and p[1] = 43605 (which is 1010 1010 0101 0101)

Comment: @Raftel "Why casting short* to int* shows incorrect value" --> the value is not incorrect.  Asserting the value must be 1 is incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most systems you're likely to interact with these days use *little-endian byte ordering*, which mean that the least significant byte comes first.

So the bytes starting at `p[1]` contain 0x01 0x00, not 0x00 0x01.  This also means the bytes starting at `p[0]` are 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00.  If these bytes are then interpreted as a 4 byte `int` it has the value 0x00010000, i.e. 65536 decimal.

Also, reinterpreting bytes in this fashion (i.e. taking a pointer to one type, casting it to another pointer type, and dereferencing), is an aliasing violation and triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so there is no guarantee this will always work in this way.

Comment: Re strict aliasing violation, I think a `union` can be used to avoid this issue.

Comment: dbush, "Most systems these days ..." its at least a 50-50 chance of being true.  Since most processors theses days are embedded ones, [0.4+ billion per year](https://electronics-sourcing.com/2020/04/09/embedded-mpus-will-drive-overall-microprocessor-market/), any reference to support _most_?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Rephrased to "most you're likely to interact with", since not many work in that space.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to *endianness* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

This determines which byte comes first in memory. Therefore, if you flip the bytes in your representation, you get exactly what you provided as the representation for `65536`.

You seem to be on a *little endian* machine.